# Why can't I return a list of specific email addresses from a Calendar invite with App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to return a list of specific email addresses of all event attendees on a GSuite calendar with a script and I can only return either an ID number or a list that appears only as "EventGuest, EventGuest, EventGuest...."

Is it possible to return the email address itself?  Thanks in advance for any guidance here!

This is the basic script that I'm working with:

```
function listCalendarAttendees(){
var calendar =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById('AnyCalendarTEST@gmail.com');
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TEST ID').getSheetByName('Bobs Calendar');
var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date(startTime.getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*7));
var events = calendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
Logger.log('Number '+events.length);
for(var x=0;x<events.length;x++){
  var event = events[x];
  var messages = event.getTitle();
  var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
  var emails = event.getCreators().toString();
  var descriptions = event.getDescription();
  var guestListLength = event.getGuestList().length;
  var guestListNames =event.getGuestList().toString();

sheet.appendRow([messages,eventStart,emails,descriptions,guestListLength,guestListNames]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Event Guest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest) is an object.  Here are it's methods:

1. [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail())
2. [getAdditionalGuests()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getAdditionalGuests())
3. [getGuestStatus()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus())
4. [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getName())

Answer (score 2):

- You want to retrieve the emails of all guests in the event.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- `getGuestList()` returns the object of `EventGuest[]`. In this case, the email can be retrieved by `getEmail()` from `EventGuest`.
- When `appendRow()` is used in the for loop, the process cost will be high. So in this modification, `setValues()` is used instead.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
for(var x=0;x<events.length;x++){
  var event = events[x];
  var messages = event.getTitle();
  var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
  var emails = event.getCreators().toString();
  var descriptions = event.getDescription();
  var guestListLength = event.getGuestList().length;
  var guestListNames =event.getGuestList().toString();

sheet.appendRow([messages,eventStart,emails,descriptions,guestListLength,guestListNames]);
}
```

To:

```
var values = [];  // Added
for(var x=0;x<events.length;x++){
  var event = events[x];
  var messages = event.getTitle();
  var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
  var emails = event.getCreators().toString();
  var descriptions = event.getDescription();
  var guestListLength = event.getGuestList().length;
  var guestListNames = event.getGuestList().map(function(e) {return e.getEmail()}).join(",");  // Modified
  values.push([messages,eventStart,emails,descriptions,guestListLength,guestListNames]);  // Modified
}
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);  // Added
```

- In this modification, the emails are separated by `,` and it is put to a cell.

#### References:

- [getGuestList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getGuestList())
- [Class EventGuest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest)
- [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.